# Visual Studio 2010 Find Green Squiggly Lines

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Is  there a way to find all the green squiggly lines in Visual Studio 2010 other than visually scanning each markup file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the error list panel, enable the warning 'option'.
[image]

See green line for Warning (2)....
[image]

The warning appears to only appear for files that are open. So keep an eye on that panel as you are working. You could do a blanket-open-all-files in VS to check for any missed warnings.

Answer (score 0):

Menu View > Error List

Green wiggly lines mean they're warnings (as opposed to the red ones, those are errors and would impede your code from building)

Double clicking separate warnings (and errors likewise) will take you to them in your code file.